# Numbering many tables' rows in which all dublicate nodes have been exluded in xslt 1.0

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have created many tables one after the other, and I want to number all their rows. First table numbering starts from 1, and every next table numbering starts from the number of its previous table's last row plus 1.
My xmlFile is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="MyXslFile.xsl"?>
<Features>
<Feature code="B" name="b1" quantity="2" price = "3.00"></Feature>
<Feature code="B" name="b2" quantity="2" price = "2.50"></Feature>
<Feature code="B" name="b2" quantity="2" price = "2.50"></Feature>
<Feature code="C" name="c1" quantity="2" price = "1.50"></Feature>
<Feature code="C" name="c2" quantity="2" price = "2.00"></Feature>
<Feature code="C" name="c2" quantity="2" price = "2.00"></Feature>
<Feature code="A" name="a1" quantity="5" price = "1.50"></Feature>
<Feature code="A" name="a1" quantity="2" price = "5.50"></Feature>
<Feature code="A" name="a2" quantity="1" price = "0.50"></Feature>
<Feature code="A" name="a2" quantity="1" price = "0.50"></Feature>
</Features>
```

My xslFile is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name="KeyName" match="Feature" use="@name" />
<xsl:key name="KeyCode" match="Feature" use="@code" />
<xsl:template match="Features">
<html>
<body>
<xsl:for-each select="Feature[generate-id() = generate-id(key('KeyCode',@code)[1])]">   
<xsl:sort select="@code" order="ascending"/> 
<table class="margin" border="2" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="50">
<tr><td colspan="5" align="center"><u><b>SECTION: <xsl:value-of select="@code"/></b></u></td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#D7E7F7">
<th align="center" width="10%">a/a:</th>
<th align="center" width="25%">Name:</th>
<th align="center" width="25%">Quantity:</th>
<th align="center" width="25%">Price:</th>
<th align="center" width="25%">Cost:</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="key('KeyCode',@code)">
<xsl:sort select="@name" order="ascending"/>
<xsl:if test="not(preceding::*[@name = current()/@name])">
<tr>
 
<!-- HERE IS WHERE I WANT YOUR HELP -->
<td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="count(key('KeyName',@name)[sum(@name) > sum(current()/@name)]) + 1" /></td>
<!-- HERE IS WHERE I WANT YOUR HELP -->

<td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>  
<td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('KeyName',@name)/@quantity)"/></td>    
<td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="@price"/></td> 
<td align="center">
<xsl:call-template name="sum">
<xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="key('KeyName',@name)" />
</xsl:call-template>
</td>
</tr> 
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
<tr>
<td colspan="4"><b>Total Cost of Section: <xsl:value-of select="@code"/></b></td>
<td align="center">
<xsl:call-template name="sum">
<xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="key('KeyCode',@code)" />
</xsl:call-template>
</td>
</tr>      
</table>
<br/>
</xsl:for-each>
<table class="margin" border="2" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="35">  
<tr bgcolor="#D7E7F7">
<td align="left" width="85%"><b>Grand Total Cost:</b></td>
<td align="center" width="15%">
<xsl:call-template name="sum">
<xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="//Feature" />
</xsl:call-template>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>    
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="sum">  
<xsl:param name="nodes" />
<xsl:param name="sum" select="0" />
<xsl:variable name="curr" select="$nodes[1]" />
<xsl:if test="$curr">
<xsl:variable name="runningsum" select="$sum + $curr/@quantity * $curr/@price" />
<xsl:call-template name="sum">
<xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes[position() &gt; 1]" />
<xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$runningsum" />
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="not($curr)">
<xsl:value-of select="$sum" />
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I apologize for presenting the whole code, but I consider I help you realize  the whole point. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is this different from your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328394/split-an-html-table-created-through-generate-id-generate-idkeykeyname-n

Comment: You did not delete the other question and you did not post the expected result I asked for, neither here not there. Please have more respect for the time of people trying to help you.

Comment: I am awfully sorry. First time in forum trying to understand the procedure. I appreciate your effort very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the created tables in a variable and then process that variable (, once converted into a node-set with e.g. `exsl:node-set` (or a similar proprietary extension function for your used XSLT 1 processor)) with templates, you can use `xsl:number` to count the `tr` elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">
<xsl:key name="KeyName" match="Feature" use="@name" />
<xsl:key name="KeyCode" match="Feature" use="@code" />
<xsl:template match="Features">
<html>
<body>
<xsl:variable name="tables-rtf">
<xsl:for-each select="Feature[generate-id() = generate-id(key('KeyCode',@code)[1])]">   
<xsl:sort select="@code" order="ascending"/> 
<table class="margin" border="2" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="50">
<tr><td colspan="5" align="center"><u><b>SECTION: <xsl:value-of select="@code"/></b></u></td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#D7E7F7">
<th align="center" width="10%">a/a:</th>
<th align="center" width="25%">Name:</th>
<th align="center" width="25%">Quantity:</th>
<th align="center" width="25%">Price:</th>
<th align="center" width="25%">Cost:</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="key('KeyCode',@code)">
<xsl:sort select="@name" order="ascending"/>
<xsl:if test="not(preceding::*[@name = current()/@name])">
<tr>
 
<!-- HERE IS WHERE I WANT YOUR HELP -->
<td align="center"></td>
<!-- HERE IS WHERE I WANT YOUR HELP -->

<td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>  
<td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('KeyName',@name)/@quantity)"/></td>    
<td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="@price"/></td> 
<td align="center">
<xsl:call-template name="sum">
<xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="key('KeyName',@name)" />
</xsl:call-template>
</td>
</tr> 
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
<tr>
<td colspan="4"><b>Total Cost of Section: <xsl:value-of select="@code"/></b></td>
<td align="center">
<xsl:call-template name="sum">
<xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="key('KeyCode',@code)" />
</xsl:call-template>
</td>
</tr>      
</table>
<br/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($tables-rtf)/table"/>
<table class="margin" border="2" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="35">  
<tr bgcolor="#D7E7F7">
<td align="left" width="85%"><b>Grand Total Cost:</b></td>
<td align="center" width="15%">
<xsl:call-template name="sum">
<xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="//Feature" />
</xsl:call-template>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>    
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table/tr[position() > 2]/td[1]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="table-pos">
      <xsl:number count="table"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="row-pos">
      <xsl:number count="tr" level="any"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$row-pos - 2 * $table-pos"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

If you are working with XSLT inside IE or the old Microsoft Edge which use MSXML as the XSLT processor then change the code to

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exsl msxml"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:key name="KeyName" match="Feature" use="@name" />
<xsl:key name="KeyCode" match="Feature" use="@code" />
<xsl:template match="Features">
<html>
<body>
<xsl:variable name="tables-rtf">
<xsl:for-each select="Feature[generate-id() = generate-id(key('KeyCode',@code)[1])]">   
<xsl:sort select="@code" order="ascending"/> 
<table class="margin" border="2" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="50">
<tr><td colspan="5" align="center"><u><b>SECTION: <xsl:value-of select="@code"/></b></u></td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#D7E7F7">
<th align="center" width="10%">a/a:</th>
<th align="center" width="25%">Name:</th>
<th align="center" width="25%">Quantity:</th>
<th align="center" width="25%">Price:</th>
<th align="center" width="25%">Cost:</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="key('KeyCode',@code)">
<xsl:sort select="@name" order="ascending"/>
<xsl:if test="not(preceding::*[@name = current()/@name])">
<tr>
 
<!-- HERE IS WHERE I WANT YOUR HELP -->
<td align="center"></td>
<!-- HERE IS WHERE I WANT YOUR HELP -->

<td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>  
<td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('KeyName',@name)/@quantity)"/></td>    
<td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="@price"/></td> 
<td align="center">
<xsl:call-template name="sum">
<xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="key('KeyName',@name)" />
</xsl:call-template>
</td>
</tr> 
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
<tr>
<td colspan="4"><b>Total Cost of Section: <xsl:value-of select="@code"/></b></td>
<td align="center">
<xsl:call-template name="sum">
<xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="key('KeyCode',@code)" />
</xsl:call-template>
</td>
</tr>      
</table>
<br/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="function-available('exsl:node-set')">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($tables-rtf)/table"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="function-available('msxml:node-set')">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="msxml:node-set($tables-rtf)/table"/>
  </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
<table class="margin" border="2" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="35">  
<tr bgcolor="#D7E7F7">
<td align="left" width="85%"><b>Grand Total Cost:</b></td>
<td align="center" width="15%">
<xsl:call-template name="sum">
<xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="//Feature" />
</xsl:call-template>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>    
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table/tr[position() > 2]/td[1]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="table-pos">
      <xsl:number count="table"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="row-pos">
      <xsl:number count="tr" level="any"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$row-pos - 2 * $table-pos"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @kapopoulosjohn, your `for-each` creating the `table` elements in my suggestion is used inside of an `xsl:variable`. that variable is the processed as shown, so I don't understand why you claim you can't use it as the above has the complete change to your original code that is necessary.

Comment: @kapopoulosjohn, which XSLT 1 processor do you use?

Comment: XSLT 1.0 installed upon windows 7 professional installation

Comment: @kapopoulosjohn, on Windows you can run different XSLT processors, how do you use XSLT exactly? Do you run MSXML, Microsoft's COM based, XSLT 1.0 processor, for instance? Or do you run XSLT in the browser. which one?

Comment: @kapopoulosjohn, see whether the edit helps that has a second code sample trying to be compatible with both Microsoft's legacy MSXML (for instance, used in IE) and other XSLT 1 processors supporting `exsl:node-set`.

Comment: Very good approach but none of our computers  supports exsl:node-set. Is it possible to handle it through xsl:call-template with param=count(key('KeyCode',@code)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('KeyName',@name)[1])])" which hold the count of each table rows?

Comment: @kapopoulosjohn, did you see the suggestion to use `msxml:node-set` as an alternative? Or can you please tell us which XSLT processor you use or in which environment exactly (browser?) you run your XSLT code?

Comment: @kapopoulosjohn, it would really help if you edit your question and clearly show which numbering you expect for that sample you have shown. It is not clear from the description, other than that I think you want to number the created rows of the (temporary) result, but the used numbering in my sample in the answer was more meant as an example you could then adapt on your own to your own, exact needs you did never state so far.